# javascript, добавить в root переменную

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь добавить переменную в :root таким образом

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--partner-color', color);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но он не входит в :root

Как задать переменную конкретно в `:root`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за `:root`?

Comment: @Darth обновил вопрос, добавил картинку

Answer (score 2):

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(`:root{--partner-color:#4444FF}`,4);
```

Для добавления правил используйте один из этих типов:

```
const unsigned short STYLE_RULE = 1;
const unsigned short CHARSET_RULE = 2;
const unsigned short IMPORT_RULE = 3;
const unsigned short MEDIA_RULE = 4;
const unsigned short FONT_FACE_RULE = 5;
const unsigned short PAGE_RULE = 6;
const unsigned short MARGIN_RULE = 9;
const unsigned short NAMESPACE_RULE = 10;
```

Comment: Я пробывал. но мне возвращает ошибку Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule

Comment: Попробуйте указать `CSSRule`. Изменил ответ.